# How to create a scheduled update in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cron

I want to create a schedule update to my ios, lets say for example every five days my app will fetch something to the internet and update the database I also want user to set the interval. I want to know where to start and any guides out there? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app won't be able to retrieve this information in the background. What you can do is set up an entry in `NSUserDefaults` with a UNIX timestamp of the last update and check that ever so often while the app is running or when it starts up. From there, if the timestamp is older than a week (as you mention in your question), you can just call the method that handles the updates from the server.

Pseudocode:

```
if (currentTimestamp - lastUpdateTimestamp <= (60 * 60 * 24 * 7)) {
    [self updateFromServer];
}
```